# A better way to handle grabbing an object from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON object with, say, 500 objects in an array. At the moment, to find the one I want, I'm using jQuery's "each" and comparing each object's id with the id I'm looking for, like so:

```
var desiredID = 500;
$.each(myObj.arrayOfObjects, function(k, oneObject){
    if((oneObject.lineid * 1) === (desiredID * 1)){
        // hooray! I have found my object
    }
});
```

Is there a better, more efficient way? The array of objects could potentially get impressively large.

(In this instance, I'm using jQuery, but it could be vanilla javascript, too.)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find , if you don't need IE support.  And if you do I'm sure there's a polyfill some where.

Comment: You can achieve similar result using vanilla javascript as well:
`myObj.arrayOfObjects.find(oneObject => (oneObject.lineid * 1) === (desiredID *1))`

Comment: Though, from a data model standpoint, one could argue if the element have an "id", they might could be better represented as a map.  Then id lookups are super easy

Comment: Side note; also not entirely sure why you are multiplying the `desiredID` by 1...

Comment: @Taplar I'll bet it's to convert from string to int.

Comment: @Barmar I get that for the lineid.  But not for the other variable

Comment: @Taplar Those pesky integers keep changing to strings, don't you know? :)

Comment: If `lineid` is a string value then you can use == (double equals) instead of ===.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with vanilla js:

```
const obj = arrayOfObjects.find(({ lineid }) => lineid === desiredID)
```

if you want to convert string to number, use this triks:

```
         +'1' === 1 // true
        ~~'1' === 1 // true
  Number('1') === 1 // true
parseInt('1') === 1 // true
```

and for the desiredID you don't have to cast, because you know it's number

Comment: for the sake of my own education: is Array.find() that much more efficient than just writing your own loop and checking against each? If so, why?

Comment: it depends on what size it is, but for the most part yes

Comment: Interesting... so up to a certain size array it is more efficient and then it stops being the faster way as the array grows? Or the opposite?

Comment: now it also depends on which search algorithm you write, if it is just 'for' is the same thing

Comment: Also keep in mind, if you do not break out of your for loop once you find what you are looking for, an each will evaluate every element even once it is found, where as a `find()` will stop on the first match immediately

Comment: Yeah I had sort of envisioned a loop with a break condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
myObj.mappedObjects = myObj.arrayOfObjects.reduce((r, e) => {
    r[+e.lineid] = e;
    return r;
}, {});

var desiredID = 500;
myObj.mappedObjects[desiredID];
```

Given that you mentioned possibly having 500ish elements, if there is the potential of having to look up elements repeatedly, I would suggest converting the array into a map, for quick id lookups going forward.

If the endpoint, or where ever, you are getting the original data could put it in that format to begin with, even better.

Comment: If you are looking for a single time in object, then 'reduce' it will consume much more than 'find'

Comment: @Chris perhaps you missed my comment about repetitions?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't paying attention